# Scheduled Task 'hangs' and blocks Octopus when it is trying to disable the task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2019, octopus

In our organization Octopus is used to deploy on-premise web applications and background tasks on a Windows Server. During deployment Octopus disables all scheduled tasks before deploying several console applications as scheduled tasks.

We have a long standing problem with Octopus being unable to disable the scheduled task because according to the status the task is 'running'. Although the status is 'running' we can see in the logging the console application has finished it's process and stopped running but the task still keeps the status 'running' for a long time (console app finishes in seconds but the task stays open for more than 10 minutes, sometimes 50 minutes or more).

The deployment of Octopus is blocked because of the 'running' state of the task. The weird thing here is that at the moment you open the Scheduled Task Manager the task suddenly finishes and Octopus continues it's deployment process with the next step.

This problem makes quick deployments impossible. Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before and found a solution for it?

Comment: Have you contacted octopus support via support@octopus.com? They're really good, and quick to respond. Also, are you using a Community process step such as https://library.octopus.com/step-templates/1be30b21-ba58-4667-bff4-2d0ef9a806af, or an out-of-the-box step?

Comment: Lastly, there's an `octopus-deploy` tag on Stack Overflow, this question might be better there.

Comment: @spikey_richie Yeah, my colleagues at Data Management and Hosting Services did ask this question at Octopus but there has not been an answer to the problem as off yet.

Comment: @spikey_richie Strange, I would think these kind of questions should be asked here and not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @spikey_richie B.t.w. I don't think it's an Octopus problem but a Windows problem since the Task is 'hanging' not Octopus. Octopus just waiting for the Task to finish which I think is correct behavior.

Comment: Did you have a look at the community process step?

Comment: @spikey_richie No, where can I find that?

Comment: @spikey_richie Found it already. Looks OK to me.

Comment: By "Looks OK to me." do you mean, the community process step has fixed your issue? Or do you mean, you can't see anything wrong with the process template?

Comment: @spikey_richie The latter. I don't see anything wrong with the comm process template. It did put me on another track. I found that there is another PS command with which you can stop all process from the task. I've asked our Hosting services people to take a look at that.